# What is the official documentation of Scala?

Tags: scala

I see two links whenever searching up official documentation for Scala:

This: https://www.scala-lang.org/

And this link: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/

What is the difference between the two? Which one is the official documentation for the language, or is there some other link?

Comment: One is the auto generated Scala doc will cover everything, the other is the language's website that has tutorials etc.

Comment: All of the official documentation is ultimately reachable starting from https://www.scala-lang.org/

Answer (score 5):

[docs.scala-lang.org](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/) gives links to main sources of documentation, for example,

- [Scala Language Specification](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/) (SLS)
- [Scala Library API](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/)

The source code of SLS is at https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/2.13.x/spec which can be useful for searching for a particular symbol in SLS via IDE (because browsers make it hard). SLS is the authoritative reference on Scala. [contributors.scala-lang.org](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/) and [scala/contributors](https://gitter.im/scala/contributors) is where in-depth discussion on design of Scala happen.

For a more approachable user guide from the designer of Scala consider [Programming in Scala](https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/) which is authored by Martin Odersky et al.